# connectionStrings in web.config is missing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config

I have an MVC project with EF, when I first created it I didn't define a connection string in the DBContext because I wanted to use the defaults, but I opened the web.config file and I didn't find the `connectionStrings` element!
I want to see the name of the database and which SQL server is used?..

**Edit**

Here is the my model classes:

```
namespace MVCAppForTests.Models
{
    public class BookContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
    public enum Rating
    {
        Excellent,
        VeryGood,
        Good,
        OK,
        Bad
    }
    public class Book
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Author { get; set; } = "Anonymous";
        public Rating Rating { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    }
    public class Initializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<BookContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(BookContext context)
        {
            var _books = new List<Book>
        {
            new Book { ID=1, Title="Awful Streets", Author="Tom Raouf", Rating= Rating.Good},
            new Book { ID=2, Title="Green Lights", Author="Sam Bruce", Rating= Rating.Bad},
            new Book { ID=3, Title="Bloodish breaths", Author="Yara Tarek", Rating= Rating.VeryGood},
            new Book { ID=4, Title="Happy inside", Author="Norman Zory", Rating= Rating.Bad},
            new Book { ID=5, Title="I lived again", Author="Adrian T. William", Rating= Rating.Excellent},
            new Book { ID=6, Title="And she knocked a door", Author="Tom Raouf", Rating= Rating.OK}
        };
            _books.ForEach(c => context.Books.Add(c));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="MVCAppForTests.Models.BookContext, MVCAppForTests" >
        <databaseInitializer type="MVCAppForTests.Models.Initializer, MVCAppForTests"></databaseInitializer>
      </context>
    </contexts>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly? Does your program actually run?

Comment: Yes, it's running,  without a connectionStrings element. I found the database in the SQLEpress, but how it determined the connection information

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework is all about conventions. If you don't provide it with a connection string (name), it will determine one by convention.

This is explained in [MSDN: Entity Framework Connections and Models](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592674(v=vs.113).aspx):

> If you have not done any other configuration in your application, then calling the parameterless constructor on DbContext will cause DbContext to run in Code First mode with a database connection created by convention.
>
> [...]
>
> In this example DbContext uses the namespace qualified name of your derived context class—Demo.EF.BloggingContext—as the database name and creates a connection string for this database using either SQL Express or LocalDb. If both are installed, SQL Express will be used.

Comment: I created many projects before without calling the `DBContext` constructor , and yet it define it in the web.config

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that comment.

Comment: I mean that this isn't the first time I create a context class this way (not passing the name parameter in base class constructor/ using parameterless constructor) because with many demos I don't bother defining it. howevere the connecton string is created on my behalf

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're getting at. If you don't define a connection string in the configuration, and you don't pass a string to the DbContext constructor, then Entity Framework will deduct the database name based on your DbContext-derived class's name. That's you question, right?

Comment: I figured it out, the `connectionStrings` element will only exist if I used individual user accounts, it will not exist if I used no authentication.